# PowerShell: Comparing Object stored in an array result unequal

Tags: powershell, comparison

In following code sample, the comparison of original object with its stored copy in an array results in unequal status. I want to understand this phenomena why they are not equal:

```
$MyArray=@()
$MyCFG="" | Select-Object -Property ProjName,ProCFG

$MyCFG.ProjName="p1"
$MyCFG.ProCFG="c1"
$MyArray+=$MyCFG.PsObject.Copy()

$MyCFG.ProjName="p2"
$MyCFG.ProCFG="c2"
$MyArray+=$MyCFG.PsObject.Copy()

$MyCFG.ProjName="p3"
$MyCFG.ProCFG="c3"
$MyArray+=$MyCFG.PsObject.Copy()


ForEach($obj in $MyArray)
{
    if ($MyCFG -eq $obj)
    {Write-Host "Equal"}
    else
    {Write-Host "Unequal"}

}
```

The last object values i.e.  $MyCFG.ProjName="p3" and $MyCFG.ProCFG="c3" are supposed to be same as stored in $MyArray, but they results in Unequal as well.

Although, it can compare properly by comparing its property values i.e:

```
if (($MyCFG.ProjName -eq $obj.ProjName) -and ($MyCFG.ProCFG -eq $obj.ProCFG))
```

but wondering why Objects comparison results as unequal...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `compare-object` in this way

```
ForEach($obj in $MyArray)
{ 
    if (compare-object $obj $mycfg -Property Projname,procfg)
    {Write-Host "Unequal"}
    else
    {Write-Host "Equal"}
}
```

Comparing the `properties` you need ( all in this case ) and test if there's some difference.

Comment: +1 Another note for the OP: instead of explicitly writing the result to host, you could take advantage of `Compare-Object` not returning anything when it is true to return a boolean instead:  `@(Compare-Object $obj $MyCFG -Property projname,procfg).Length -eq 0`

Comment: @HyperAnthony Try the code with my solution: there is not output from the compare-object in any conditions..

Comment: Right, it wasn't necessarily speaking to your example but I wanted to offer OP some usage advice for Compare-Object as they would hopefully follow-up on this answer by experimenting a bit with the cmdlet. (Like what would happen if it wasn't embedded in an if statement)

Comment: @HyperAnthony hu.. ok! My misunderstanding ;)

Comment: There are parameters to Compare-Object to tell it to output various combinations of Left-Only, Right-Only, or Both